# python: inserting a variable value into a variable name

Tags: python, variables

I would like to insert the value of a variable into the name of another variable in python.  In a shell script this would be something like:

```
for n in `more list`  
do  
var_$n = some_calculation  
done
```

but I can't see how to do a similar thing in python.  Is there a way or should I be using an alternative approach?
thanks,
Andy

Comment: in a shell script, that is also not correct. you have to use an `eval`

Answer (score 20):

Don't do it! Having variable names that change depending on the value of a variable leads to unnecessary complications. A cleaner way is to use a dictionary:

```
vr={}
for n in alist:
    vr[n]=some_calculation()
```

Comment: Thanks! (and to other replies).  This looks less fragile than my shell script approach too.

Comment: yeah for this task dict is fine, but what do when some value arrives and i have constants defined with values already .. I just could catch exception and do: `try: class.${TYPE}...` i know that this comes from php but it's saves so many nerves..

Answer (score 6):

```
for n in more_list:
    globals()["var_"+str(n)]=some_calculation
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this in a class?
like self.["var_" + str(n)] = value ???

Comment: @mr777, for classes it is even simpler: you can use `setattr(self, key, value)` or `self.__setattr__(key, value)`. See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) for details

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not perfect, but two possible solutions:

```
>>> name = "var_1"
>>> locals()[name] = 5
>>> print var_1
5
>>> exec(name + "= 6")
>>> print var_1
6
```

Comment: But be aware that the `locals()` approach does not work inside functions. See here: http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/dynamic-variable-declaration-140173.html It is still valid, I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is not prefer to have variable like
var1 = foo
var2 = bar
var${id} is actually a group of variable with similar characteristics that's why you would like to name it in such ways.
Try using list or dict which group variables in a more efficient way!

Answer (score 0):

a dict is one way to maintain an associative array.

```
dict = {}
dict[str] = calc();
```

Comment: Never name your dict "`dict`"; this shadows the builtin `dict`, which is the dictionary type, which you may need to call at some point.